# Cargar formato de fecha datetime-local en input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, vue3

Estoy trabajando con Vue 3 y utilizando moment js, estoy con esta funcion:

```
 //Funcion para obtener el tiempo actual, tiempo al crear o editar un registro
    const horaActual = ()=> {
       const hoy = moment().format('D-MM-Y H:mm');
       return hoy;
   };
```

y lo que deseo lograr es cargar esta fecha en un input del `type="datetime-local "` para reutilizar codigo tengo unos componentes y en este caso tengo el siguiente, el cual importo en un componente principal.

```
<template>
    <div class="rounded bg-gray-200">
        <label class="" :for="name">
            {{ label }}
        </label>
        <input :value="model" type="datetime-local" :id="name" class="bg-white rounded w-full text-black focus:outline-none border-b-2 border-white focus:border-teal-400 transition duration-500 h-7" />
        <div v-if="$store.state.form_errors[name]" class="text-red-500">
            {{ $store.state.form_errors[name] }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "InputDateTime",
        props: ["name", "model", "label"],
    }
</script>
```

En mi componente principal lo llamo pero no logro que me cargue la fecha con el formato que corresponde

```
<div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3 lg:col-span-3">
    <label for="fecha" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">Fecha recepción</label>
    <input-date-time name="fecha" :model="horaActual()" @input="$emit('update:fecha', $event.target.value)" autocomplete="family-name" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-md" />
    <p>{{horaActual()}}</p>
</div>
```

[image: ![image|690x111](upload://oBjtp4JzBldZqCpvgYyFPiNxvOs.png)]

Alguien me puede dar una ayuda a este problema, es bastante raro y absurdo a mi parecer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si miras [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) del `<input type="datetime-local">` verás que dice que su **value** debe estar en un [formato concreto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#local_date_and_time_strings) que no estás usando en tu string.

La solución pasa por cambiar esta línea:

```
const hoy = moment().format('D-MM-Y H:mm');
```

por esta otra:

```
const hoy = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm');
```

para obtener el formato que se espera para ese campo, que sería este:

```
2022-05-23T20:50
```

Comment: Por ahi iba la cosa amigo, intente con otro formato que he poosteado en mi respuesta... gracias por el link amigo!

Comment: Vale, he modificado mi respuesta con tu dato para no confundir a quien la lea, ya que la has aceptado.  En realidad tenia mis dudas sobre ese formato, y no investigue el formato de **moment** pues me creia lo que habias puesto en la pregunta, donde habia esto: `<p>{{horaActual()}}</p>` y en la captura salia completa aunque no en el orden correcto: `23-05-2022 20:50`, y deduje sin verificarlo que esas letras del formato estaban bien y tan solo debia cambiar su orden.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad era encontre probando en la pagina de firefox otro formato que me dio la solucion, un problema bastante tonto pero bien especifico a la vez.

`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm`

quedando asi mi solucion

```
//Funcion para obtener el tiempo actual, tiempo al crear o editar un registro
const horaActual = ()=> {
    //const hoy = moment().format('D-MM-Y H:mm');
    const hoy = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm');
    return hoy;
};
```